# One-sided limits question

Tags: functions, limits

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{1-\cos(5x)}{x^2} & x > 0 \\ \\
            \frac{e^x + 2x -2}{x} & x < 0
        \end{cases}
$$

Find the limits for $x\rightarrow 0^-$ and for $x\rightarrow 0^+$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you know what it means $x\rightarrow 0^-$ and $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos 5x}{x^2}=\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos u}{(\frac u 5)^2}$$
while 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^x+2x-2}{x}$$
is not indeterminate.